# Configure rules in Detekt

Tags: kotlin, detekt

I am adding Detekt to a new project.
But, I find that some rules are too strict.

How can I implement my own thresholds for a few rules?

I don't want to use [Baseline files](https://detekt.dev/baseline.html), because this is new code and we don't want to consider some things code smells.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to configure Detekt via configuration files.

As per [Detekt's documentation](https://detekt.dev/configurations.html), with my emphasis:

> detekt allows easily to just ***pick the rules you want and configure them the way you like***. For example if you want to allow up to 20 functions inside a Kotlin file ***instead of the default threshold***, write:
>
> ```
> complexity:
> TooManyFunctions:
>   thresholdInFiles: 20
> ```

You'll want to create a `config` folder in the root of your project, and add `detekt.yaml` to it. This config will contain all the rules that you want to override the default, or all the rules (establishing the defaults as the correct value).

For more information, [check the official documentation on configuration](https://detekt.dev/configurations.html)

Comment: what command do you use for it to take effect?

Comment: `detekt` should run the task with the modified configuration automatically